# Oracle. запрос, фильтрующий строки по максимальному идентификатору или дате

Tags: sql, oracle, сортировка, запрос, select

Представьте систему контроля сотрудника, где каждый год он должен продлевать свой контракт, а дата продления фиксироваться в таблицу, причем старые записи сохраняются в таблице.
Таблица выглядит так:

```
|ID|START_DATE|END_DATE  |NAME |
|0 |28.11.2016|31.12.2017|Игорь|
|1 |25.11.2020|31.12.2021|Маша |
|2 |18.11.2018|31.12.2019|Игорь|
|3 |03.12.2019|31.12.2020|Игорь|
|4 |05.11.2021|31.12.2022|Маша |
|5 |02.11.2005|31.12.2006|Павел|
|6 |05.12.2020|31.12.2021|Павел|
|7 |12.12.2021|31.12.2022|Павел|
```

Необходимо выводить список актуальных дат на каждое имя сотрудника, допустим, на одного условного "Игоря" будет 20 записей, но нужно вывести только ту, которая имеет самую актуальную дату.
**Необходимо создать запрос, фильтрующий END_DATE (либо ID) таким образом, чтобы к каждому NAME была выведена только одна строка с самой новой END_DATE (либо ID)**, т.е. :

```
|ID|START_DATE|END_DATE  |NAME |
|3 |03.12.2019|31.12.2020|Игорь|
|4 |05.11.2021|31.12.2022|Маша |
|7 |12.12.2021|31.12.2022|Павел|
```

*P.S Естественно, данные упрощены в угоду вопроса. А пример с "системой" и "приложением" выдуман в угоду упрощения представления.*

Comment: Нумеруем в CTE в группе по сотруднику по убыванию дат, берём только записи с первым номером.

Comment: @Akina я примерно хотел сделать так, но мой мозг совсем мягкий чтобы додуматься до полноценной реализации, к тому же в гуглах данное я не нашел, я подумал что данный вопрос с решением оказался бы полезен комьюнити.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH 
cte AS ( SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY start_date DESC) rn
         FROM src_table )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
```